# Java Observer Pattern finding sender?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

observer.update();

Above method makes the visibility of observers "GONE", but i want to change all other observers except sender observer. How can i control this ?

My all actions are observer and register themself in their constructor like below,

```
public class ParentAction extends AbstractAction implements IActionObserver{
    private ArrayList<IAction> lSubItems;
    private View subView;

    public ParentAction( String ItemText,int drawable,ArrayList<IAction> SubItems) {
        super(ItemText,drawable);       
        lSubItems = SubItems;   
        ActionHolder.getInstance().registerObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        getSubView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }  ...
```

**ActionHolder**

```
public class ActionHolder implements IActionSubject {
    private static ActionHolder uniqueActionHolder;
    private ArrayList observers;

    private ActionHolder() {
        observers = new ArrayList();
    }

    public static synchronized ActionHolder getInstance() {
        if (uniqueActionHolder == null) {
            uniqueActionHolder = new ActionHolder();
        }
        return uniqueActionHolder;
    }

    public void registerObserver(IActionObserver o) {
        observers.add(o);
    }

    public void removeObserver(IActionObserver o) {
        int i = observers.indexOf(o);
        if (i >= 0) {
            observers.remove(i);
        }

    }

    public void notifyObserver() {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {            
            IActionObserver observer = (IActionObserver) observers.get(i);          
            observer.update();
        }
    }

    public void actionClicked(View view) {
        notifyObserver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this your own implementation of the observer pattern? If so, you can modify the `notify` method, for instance:

```
public void notifyObserver(IAction sender) {
    for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {            
        IActionObserver observer = (IActionObserver) observers.get(i);  
        if (observer != sender)  
            observer.update();
    }
}
```

and call this as

```
ActionHolder.getInstance().notifyObserver(this);
```

**Alternatively**, you could add a flag in your action class:

```
private bool sender = false;
```

set the flag before notifying:

```
sender = true;
ActionHolder.getInstance().notifyObserver();
```

and use this flag in the `update`:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    if (!sender) {
        getSubView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    sender = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it help me to find the way, I have IAction interface which is implemented by abstractAction. So notifyObserver(IAction action) ... worked for me , thanks again

Comment: @talhakosen ok, wasn't sure about the exact hierarchy, so I changed from `IAction` to `AbstractAction`, but I changed it back now :) and yw

Comment: yes i just want to give more info for other developer who will need this answer :) Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You raising event in `actionClicked` method and then notifying all observers. Just pass a reference to your sender observer to skip its refreshing later.

If i got your code correctly, you can achieve that by controlling sender with your `view`

```
public void actionClicked(View view) {
    notifyObserver(view);
}

public void notifyObserver(View view) {
   for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {            
        IActionObserver observer = (IActionObserver) observers.get(i);          
        observer.update(view);
   }
}
```

And `update` method skips current view

```
@Override
public void update(View view) {
   if (!getSubView().equals(view)) {
       getSubView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is an alternative also +1